# How to test if $a is divisible by $b when $b is larger than $a

Tags: php, math, division, modulus

I'm trying to work out if one string, $a, is divisible by another, $b.

All of the examples I can find tell me to use modulus, e.g.:

```
if(($a %$b) == 0) : echo "Is dividible" ; endif;
```

However, because modulus returns the remainder of the calculation, this doesn't work if $b is larger than $a, because there's still no remainder.

How do I check divisibility where $b is sometimes (but not always) larger than $a?

Comment: `if($a % $b == 0 || $b % $a == 0)`?

Comment: You mean if $a / $b will return an integer result (no remainder)..... if $b is greater than $a, it will always have a remainder`

Comment: if it did not work if `$b > $a` why don't you ensure `$b < $a` with some if before that code? well, @Federico had a straight answer.

Comment: If `$b > $a` then remainder is `$a`. Your formula is correct.

Comment: if $a is greater or equal than $b => test modulus against zero, else => not divisible.

Comment: Possibly the canonical [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090475/checking-if-a-number-is-divisible-by-6-php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090475/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you do this as a function:

```
function isDivisible($smaller,$bigger){
    //handle division by zero, and hmm.. let's cover negative numbers too
    if($smaller<=0) return false;
    if($smaller>$bigger) return false;
    return !($bigger % $smaller);
}
```

The negation `!` should be a working and elegant way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
echo ( ($a < $b) && (($a % $b) == 0) ) ? "Is dividible" : "Is not divisable" ;
```

Comment: If $b is larger than $b, you will ALWAYS get a fraction. What exactly do you mean by "Find out if dividable by" Do you mean the divide returns a whole number? If so, then all you need to do it the above. If you mean in geek speak dividable, then everything is dividable by everything apart from zero (divide by zero - error)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($a==$b)
{echo "divisible a and b are equal";
}
else if($a>$b){
   if(($a %$b) == 0) : echo "Is dividible" ; endif;    
}
else{
echo "\$b is either large or equal to \$a";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work:

```
$a = 7;
$b = 14;

//echo ( ($a > $b) && ( ($a % $b) == 0) ) ? "is divisible":"no divisible";

echo ( ($a < $b) && (($b % $a) == 0) ) ? "Is dividible" : "Is not divisable" ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ternary operator as example given below

```
(($a%$b)==0)?echo "Is divisible": echo "not divisible";
```